# How does this CSS converts into JSS?

Tags: javascript, css, jss

I'm trying to get a specific class to change styles when its parent class gets hovered, in CSS it'd be this:

```
.App:hover customButton {
  background: black;
}
```

I've tried doing this in JSS but with no success:

```
export const appStyles = createUseStyles({
  app: {
    width: '90vw',
    height: '90vh',
    margin: '0 auto',
    background: 'blue',
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    '&:hover': {
      customStyles: {
        background: 'black'
      }
    }
  },
  customStyles: {
    background: 'white';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're using the [nested plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0-alpha.3#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) then use `$` to reference another local rule:

```
export const appStyles = createUseStyles({
  app: {
    width: '90vw',
    height: '90vh',
    margin: '0 auto',
    background: 'blue',
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    // ------v  Note the "$" here
    '&:hover $customStyles': {
      background: 'black'
    }
  },
  customStyles: {
    background: 'white';
  }
});
```